# PKCS5 Padding with node.js crypto

Tags: node.js, cryptography, node-crypto

The docs for node.js crypto indicate that padding is inserted automatically into the input stream.  I have a simple test program that needs to compute the SHA1 hash of a cleartext, then encrypt that 20-byte hash use AES-256/CBC with PKCS5 padding.  Here is my test code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var key = [ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
            0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
            0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
            0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f ];

var iv = [ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
           0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f ];

var test_string = "This is the string I am signing";

// Create SHA1 hash of our string
var sha1Hash = crypto.createHash("sha1");
sha1Hash.update(test_string, "utf8");
var sha1 = sha1Hash.digest();

var aesCipher =
        crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", (new Buffer(key)), (new Buffer(iv)));
aesCipher.update(sha1, "binary");
var encrypted = aesCipher.final("binary");

fs.writeFile('data/node_encrypted.bin', encrypted, function (error) {
    if (error)
        throw error;
    console.log("File saved!");
});
```

However, this produces a file that is only 23 bytes in length.  I expected that with proper PKCS5 padding, the output would be 32-bytes.  What am I missing?

Comment: Had the same problem. Great question and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one thing, you're discarding the first part of the encrypted contents by ignoring the return value of `aesCipher.update()`. Also, since your `update()` does not specify an output encoding, it's returning a Buffer, yet your `final()` is returning a 'binary' string. You might try instead:

```
var encrypted = Buffer.concat([
  aesCipher.update(sha1, "binary"),
  aesCipher.final()
]);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This was the problem.  It wasn't clear to me that cipher.final() would not produce the entire encrypted contents.

Comment: Thank you!

This helped me solve a similar issue with decryption where I was seeing partially decrypted strings.

Solved it with a similar approach:

`return Buffer.concat([decipher.update(new Buffer(data, 'base64')),decipher.final()]).toString('utf8')`

Comment: I agree, @GregR - the Node docs don't seem very clear here:  
"The cipher.update() method can be called multiple times with new data until cipher.final() is called." 
My understanding here was that final() will accumulate all update() calls.